# No output from Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("ArenasMembers.xml"));

    var query = from p in xml.Descendants("members")
                select new
                {
                    Name = p.Element("name").Value,
                    Email = p.Attribute("email").Value
                };

    foreach (var member in query)
    {
        Response.Write("Employee: " + member.Name + " " + member.Email + "<br />");
    }
}
```

Which, using the hover information in Visual Studio, is reading the XNL file in correctly, however the foreach is not outputting any of the records.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<members>
    <member>
        <arena>EAA Office</arena>
        <memberid>1</memberid>
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
        <email>test@gmail.com</email>
    </member>
    <member>
        <arena>EAA Office</arena>
        <memberid>2</memberid>
        <name>John Bull</name>
        <email>jb@ehotmail.org</email>
    </member>
    <member>
        <arena>O2 Arena</arena>
        <memberid>3</memberid>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <email>john.doe@o2arena.co.uk</email>
    </member>
    <member>
        <arena>O2 Arena</arena>
        <memberid>4</memberid>
        <name>Bernard Cribbins</name>
        <email>bernard@gmail.com</email>
    </member>
    <member>
        <arena>Colourline Arena</arena>
        <memberid>5</memberid>
        <name>John Bon Jovi</name>
        <email>jbj@gmail.com</email>
    </member>
    <member>
        <arena>NIA</arena>
        <memberid>6</memberid>
        <name>Rhianna</name>
        <email>skimpy@gmail.com</email>
    </member>
</members>
```

Can you see what is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that `XElement xml = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("ArenasMembers.xml"));` is loading the XML?

Comment: It is - "using the hover information in Visual Studio, is reading the XNL file in correctly"

Comment: you ought to put that code & XML into linqPad. you can then quickly test your query and see what the frel is going on.

Comment: Why do you use Element("name") but Attribute("email") that can't be right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insted of "members" try "member"...

`Descendants` returns you all the child elements under given `Element`, in your code you are querying `members` with `name` and `email`, which wont work.

*Sample Code:*

```
 var query = from p in xml.Descendants("member")
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = p.Element("name").Value,
                        Email = p.Element("email").Value
                    };
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking, unable to run the code so cannot verify.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Attribute("email") into Element("email") worked out just fine for me. tested, hopefully approved.

```
    public void XMLTEst()
    {
        var xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>"
                  + "   <members>"
                  + "  <member>"
                  + "      <arena>EAA Office</arena>                  "
                  + "      <memberid>1</memberid>                     "
                  + "      <name>Jane Doe</name>                      "
                  + "      <email>test@gmail.com</email>              "
                  + "  </member>                                      "
                  + "  <member>                                       "
                  + "      <arena>EAA Office</arena>                  "
                  + "      <memberid>2</memberid>                     "
                  + "      <name>Linda Bull</name>                    "
                  + "      <email>linda.bull@eaaoffice.org</email>    "
                  + "  </member>                                      "
                  + "  <member>                                       "
                  + "      <arena>O2 Arena</arena>                    "
                  + "      <memberid>3</memberid>                     "
                  + "      <name>John Doe</name>                      "
                  + "      <email>john.doe@o2arena.co.uk</email>      "
                  + "  </member>                                      "
                  + "  <member>                                       "
                  + "      <arena>O2 Arena</arena>                    "
                  + "      <memberid>4</memberid>                     "
                  + "      <name>Bernard Cribbins</name>              "
                  + "      <email>bernard@gmail.com</email>           "
                  + "  </member>                                      "
                  + "  <member>                                       "
                  + "      <arena>Colourline Arena</arena>            "
                  + "      <memberid>5</memberid>                     "
                  + "      <name>John Bon Jovi</name>                 "
                  + "      <email>jbj@gmail.com</email>               "
                  + "  </member>                                      "
                  + "  <member>                                       "
                  + "      <arena>NIA</arena>                         "
                  + " <memberid>6</memberid>"
                  + " <name>Rhianna</name>"
                  + "  <email>skimpy@gmail.com</email>"
                  + " </member>"
                  + "</members>";


        XElement xmlFile = XElement.Parse(xml);

        var query = from p in xmlFile.Descendants("member")
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = p.Element("name").Value,
                        Email = p.Element("email").Value
                    };


        foreach (var member in query)
        {
            Response.Write("Employee: " + member.Name + " " + member.Email + "<br />");
        }

    }
```