# Select more then one node from XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I have such XML

```
<root>
    <content>
        ....
    </content>
    <index>
        ....
    </index>
    <keywords>
        ....
    </keywords>
</root>
```

But I need to select just  and  nodes.

```
<content>
    ....
</content>
<index>
    ....
</index>
```

I found out how to select just one node.

```
XElement Content = new XElement("content", from el in xml.Elements() select el.Element("content").Elements());
```

How can I get both nodes?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810623/no-output-from-linq-to-xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var elements = 
    from element in xml.Root.Elements()
    where element.Name == "content" ||
          element.Name == "index"
    select element;
var newContentNode = new XElement("content", elements);
```

Comment: Thank you! It is precisely what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the xml file loaded, you can get all the content nodes through:

```
var cons = from con in xmlFile.Descendants("content");
```

and similarly you can get the index nodes as:

```
var idxs = from idx in xmlFile.Descendants("index")
```

I don't think you can query two nodes using one query string.

Answer (score 1):

Using lambda:

```
    var elements = document
        .Descendants()
        .Where(element => element.Name == "content" || element.Name == "index");
```